# App crashes due to UIAlerview in ios 7 ,but working fine in ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

```
alertView =[[TSAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ALERT" 
message:@"Please select type" delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

This works fine in `iOS 6`,but crashes in `iOS 7`
i made delegate to `nil`, then it worked. I guess problem might be self is deallocted by the time alert dismissed. 
My doubt is why delegate:self worked in `iOS 6` and why it is crashed in `iOS 7` ?

Can anybody help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TSAlertView is updated now to work in IOS 7. They Added a customSubview property . So Please update the latest code from here:

[TSAlertView](https://github.com/mindbrix/TSAlertView)

Comment: The same happend with UIAlertView. Could you please explain why it is crashing in iOS 7,but working with iOS 6?

Comment: In IOS7, Apple put some restrictions on UIAlertView. So it will become difficult to customize, change appearance and so on. It is difficult to say about the problem before seeing the code

Comment: the problem is in your UIAlertViewDelegate definition. show me the code for this.

Comment: Hi @manujmv,

i hav 2 controllers,
**In MyController.m** 
`- (IBAction)showAlert:(UIButton *)sender { 
ValidationController *valCont=[[ValidationController alloc]init]; 
[valCont show]; 
}` 

**In ValidationController.m** 

`-(BOOL)show{ 
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please select type" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]; 
[alertView show]; 
NSLog(@"No prob in alert"); 
return YES; 
} 
`
when OK button z clicked on alertview.app crashes in iOS 7, but the same code working on iOS 6. 
Could you please help me on this??

Comment: have u implemented any delegate methods like clickedButtonAtIndex or willDismissWithButtonIndex?